# TSL/SSL enablling in mongodb is required if my website is HTTPS enabled

Tags: mongodb, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

Our website hosted in one of AWS EC2 instance.
We have MongoDB installed in the separate EC2 instance (Note: MongoDB is not managed by AWS. We are maintaining in the EC2 server)
Our website is HTTPS enabled.
So my questions are

1. Do we still need TSL/SSL encryption for connecting to MongoDB from our website (which is in EC2), even though both are in AWS and our website is HTTPS
2. Do we see any performance issue if we enable TSL/SSL encryption for connection from the website

Comment: HTTPS prevents 3rd parties to see the data going over the network. Do you control the network between your two EC2 instances, do you have confidence that nobody can listen in there? (No, and no.)

Comment: Yeah thats true @deceze. But since we also have IP whitelisting where any connections to mongo will be from this IP. Wouldnt that be enough to avoid mongo connections from outside ?

Comment: HTTPS doesn't prevent connections from undesired clients, it protects from anyone sitting between your two EC2 instances to read the data that you're sending between them. They don't have to *connect* to anything, they just need to see the data packets on the wire go by.

Comment: Thanks @deceze for your response. 
As I said, we have IP based access to MongoDB where we have configured in AWS to allow access to MongoDB and port with only the IP of our website instance. Wouldnt that be enough in terms of security?

Comment: Again, there's a physical wire connecting your two EC2 instances; likely there's also a bunch of switches and routers sitting on that wire. HTTP traffic is plaintext, so anyone having control over any part of that "wire" or any device being able to see data going through that  "wire" (including switches and routers) can see the data in plaintext. *That's* what HTTPS prevents. It has nothing to do with connecting to Mongo.